# How can I create a simple <select> in AngularJS with an option pre-selected?

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to create a  in AngularJS. Here's what I did so far:

```
<select ng-model="inverse">
   <option value=true>Sort Up</option>
   <option value=false selected="selected">Sort Down</option>
</select>
```

I was trying to set false as the initial value. However when I look at the HTML that's created I see this and the select box does not show "Sort Down" as the default:

```
<select ng-model="inverse" class="ng-pristine ng-valid">
   <option value="? undefined:undefined ?"></option>
   <option value="true">Sort Up</option>
   <option value="false" selected="selected">Sort Down</option>
</select>
```

Can someone explain what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me:

```
<select ng-model="inverse">
   <option value="true">Sort Up</option>
   <option value="false">Sort Down</option>
</select>
```

Controller:

```
$scope.inverse = "false";
```

However, using `ng-options` is suggested.

Comment: You mention ng-options but do you think it's okay what I am doing here for this use case ? It's a very simple two state sort that will never really change. Either up or down.  Thanks

Comment: I think you can do without ng-options if its that simple.

Answer (score 0):

Set the value of inverse in the controller using:

```
$scope.inverse = true;
```

And remove the selected="selected" attribute from the option.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<select ng-init="inverse='false'" ng-model="inverse">
    <option value=true>Sort Up</option>
    <option value=false>Sort Down</option>
</select>
```